# 3D printing errors

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

From the looks of it, my blender file to me looks fine. And When I export as an .stl is shows up fine. But when I try to preview the print, it shows up hollowed in some parts. [image: Stl file]

[image: blender file]
[image: hollowed print]

If I do print, will it come out hollowed? or will it be different? How can I change the model so that when printing it comes out right?

Comment: What program are you using to 3d print?

Comment: I am using MakerBot Print

Comment: hmm. Could you send the blend file of the object?

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=uQuOlV I don't know if the link works but it should be there. Please let me know if it doesn't @caleblee